# Vuetify change global hover/active color

Tags: vuetify.js

I have multiple `v-list` in my design,

Now, how can I override hover and active colors of all related components in my app?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can change some colors using `color` prop on `v-list` component. You can pass built-in color name which you can find on the [colors page](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/styles/colors/#material-colors), hex or rgba value.
2. Additionaly you can customize many scss variables as written [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=vuetify%20scss&oq=vuetify%20scss&aqs=chrome.0.69i59j0l6.1389j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8).
3. Last but not least you can just attach some custom CSS to the specific component classes.